# Dialogflow, Maps Agent - how to get lat/long?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Dialogflow offers a pre-built agent called "Maps" that helps to catch the location from user's statement. This Maps intent resolves the location and returns data such as

1. City name (when I search for Google, Chicago)
2. Business name (when I search for Chennai)
3. subdomain-area (when I search for "where is saidapet")
4. admin-area (when I search for Schaumburg)

What is the logic behind this Agent?

Is there any schema defined anywhere so that I know which field to expect for a given search?

Is it possible to get lat/long part of this response?

Appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

When you use one of these prebuilt agents, you are basically creating a new agent of your own based on a Google-provided samplete/template.  Click on the intent definitions and you’ll see what parameter names they map things to.  You can also change these names, add parameters, remove parameters, edit the list of example utterances, etc.  What you don’t get is example fulfillment code - your on your own to do something useful with the intents Google has provided in these samples.